# How to check if a command has already been executed

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Here's the problem : I don't know how to write the script so that if I type more than once start or stop the script will print something like "Already running" or "Not running"

```
running = True
print("Type help for a list of commands. ")
while running :
    user=input("> ")
    user_input=user.upper()
    if user_input==("HELP"):
        print(f"""Type start to start the car.
Type stop to stop the car.
Type quit to quit the game.""")
    elif user_input==("START"):
        print("You started the car. ")
    elif user_input==("STOP"):
        print("You stopped the car. ")
    elif user_input==("QUIT"):
        print("You stopped the game.")
        running=False
    elif user_input!=("START") and user_input!=("STOP") and user_input!=("QUIT"):
        print("I don't understand that. ")
```

Example:

```
 >start
You started the car.
 >start
Car is already running.
 >stop
You stopped the car.
 >stop
Car isn't turned on.
```

Comment: You can add another variable above the `while` to check if the car is running, like `isCarRunning = False` and then in the **START** case, set it to `True` and in the **STOP** case, set it back to False and check the variable to see if the car is running where you need to.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for help with an assignment.

Comment: How can you demonstrate that?! I'm doing this online course https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc (1:31:13) and I was curious if could improve the code.

Comment: You could look into state machines. The reply to a command can be different in different states.

Comment: @cwallenpoole [Asking for help with assignments is allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) if the question meets normal quality standards. Please don't close questions for that reason.

Comment: @JohnKugelmansupportsMonica My apologies. It looks like has been some change in standards recently (or at least recently to me). Vote retracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you want to stop the car, you must start it first, right?

Make one global variable—let's call it `started`—and set it to `False`.
Now, when we want to "start" the car, first we need to check:

```
elif user_input==("START"):
    if started:
        print("Car is already running")
    else:
        print("You started the car")
        started = True
```

Then just do the similar statement with stopping: if `started` is `True`, then it means your car is running and you can stop it. Set `started` to `False` and print the message that car is stopped. Otherwise, you didn't even turn on the car.

P.S. Be careful: declare and initialize `started` before your while loop!

Comment: I forgot to mentinon: "if started" is literally typing: "if started==True", so it's checking if "started" equals to True.